# How can I get animated emoticons in Skype for Linux 8.11.0.4?

Tags: skype

I updated my Skype for Linux package to version 8.11.0.4 recently. In the popup window for selecting emoticons, the previewed emoticon is animated. However, emoticons in the actual chat conversation are not. They used to be animated in Skype for Linux 5. How can I make them animated again?

Comment: I have 8.11.0.4 installed on Ubuntu 17.10, and I can see the animations. Once selected and in the IM conversation, you need to click on the emoticon to make them animate. Is this not what you're seeing? What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Clicking on the emoticons does not animate them. And why should I be required to first click on them? However, I realized meanwhile that emoticons *are* animated if they appear in the last message of a conversation. Is it intentional that only those emoticons are animated? I am using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.3 LTS.